# How to subprocess when connecting to ssh

Tags: python, ssh

I have some difficulties connecting to ssh with python. Any help would be appreciated. After connecting to the ssh instance, i would like to go through the following path:

```
~$ su liquidity
(base) liquidity@beast:/home/xxxxxxx$ cd ~/liquidity-analytics
(base) liquidity@beast:~/liquidity-analytics$ source activate pluto
(pluto) liquidity@beast:~/liquidity-analytics$ python
```

But my intend send me an error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~$ su': '~$ su'
```

My code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import pluto as pl

HOST = 'ssh -p 444 XXXXXXX@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX'

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()

a = subprocess.call(['~$ su', 'liquidity'])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you connecting to an other host over ssh then the connection will be build up and closed. You should put in a single command or a command to start a script like:

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, "ls"],
               shell=False,
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or:

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, 
               "/path/to/script/on/other/host/script.py"],
               shell=False,
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In this (python) script you can do your other commands.

EDIT:
ok you need to switch to user 'liquidity' then do that in your ssh connection. For the other commands take a new variable cmd

```
cmd = "cd ~/liquidity-analytics; "
cmd += "source activate pluto; "
cmd += "python; "
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "liquidity@%s" % HOST, cmd],
           shell=False,
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand that the path to the file should be in a single command. But my issue is to activate a module. So I put the path `"/liquidity/liquidity-analytics"` but how should I activate the module to import it then please?

Comment: thank you again. It is a good improvement but I can still not import the pluto package and use it with pandas or other python packages.

Comment: i think that what you want is something other. You should read about the linux programm "expect" or python package "pexpect". That will give you what you want. See for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859455/ssh-remote-machine-and-run-the-ls-l-using-pexpect